# Unable to change cell background colour, EPPlus in C#

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I'm trying to verify that a cell in a row is not *null*. If it is *null*, I want to change the background colour of the cell to *red*. After reading how to do that, I have come up with the following code:

```
public int verifyImportFile(FileUpload fup)
    {
        int status = 0;
        //check if there is actually a file being uploaded
        if (fup.HasFile)
        {
            //load the uploaded file into the memorystream
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(fup.FileBytes))
            //Lets the server know to use the excel package
            using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(stream))
            {
                //Gets the first worksheet in the workbook
                ExcelWorksheet worksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
                //Gets the row count
                var rowCnt = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
                //Gets the column count
                var colCnt = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;
                //Beginning the loop for data gathering
                for (int i = 2; i < rowCnt; i++) //Starts on 2 because excel starts at 1, and line 1 is headers
                {
                    //If there is no value in column 3, proceed
                    if (worksheet.Cells[i, 3].Value == null)
                    {
                        worksheet.Cells[i, 3].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                        worksheet.Cells[i,3].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Red);
                        status = 1;
                    }                        
                }
                xlPackage.Save();
            }               
        }
        return status;
    }
```

What I do know from testing is that if a *null* value is found, it enters the if statement that checks for *nulls*. It seems to be running the code to change the background colour. After it loops through the entire excel sheet, the variable *status* does change to 1 and is displayed in a popup. 
From my understanding of how to do this, it is running properly but the background colour stays white.

Comment: Does it work if you just create a simple method that colors cell A1 red?

Comment: @silkfire Just made the change. It runs the code, but still doesn't change the colour

Comment: Try to seek help on their support forums maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct as far as setting the background color assuming it is being hit which have confirmed.

But how are you actually saving out the file?  Once you load to a `MemoryStream` the connection to the original byte array is severed.  You need to do a `SaveAs()` or `GetAsByteArray()` call like this:

```
xlPackage.SaveAs(new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\myFile.xls"));
```

Calling `Save()` just writes to the MemoryStream.

Comment: The more you know... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this works.
`worksheet.Cells[i, 3].Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red)`